# How to read/write a text file in qt?

Tags: qt, text, qt4, qplaintextedit

I have a QPlainTextEdit in my Form and I want to read the whole Resource.txt document which is placed in Other Files of my project and after a timer ticks i want the application save the contents of the QPlainTextEdit in the document.
I know it's a dumb question but I can't find a solution.

Comment: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfile.html

Answer (score 3):

[QTextStream.readAll()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextstream.html) lets you read a file to a `QString`. [This constructor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qplaintextedit.html#QPlainTextEdit-2) (or the method `setPlainText`) for `QPlainTextEdit` lets you set a string displayed in the editor. Use a [QTimer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtimer.html) to trigger a slot which reads the contents of the `QPlainTextEdit` into a `QString` with the [toPlainText](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qplaintextedit.html#plainText-prop) method after a desired amount of time. Write the result to file using a `QTextStream` again.

Comment: can you give me some examples

Comment: why won't you try to think a little bit, try your own code and then if it doesn't do what you want come back and ask another question? Asking for "example (ready and working) code" isn't best way to learn anything. Qt has realy great documentation that explains a lot of things

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial [Getting Started Programming with Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/gettingstartedqt.html) takes you through building a text editor, once you have followed this, try adding a `QTimer` to trigger a save.